# Uploaded images missing in Drupal

Tags: media

In my case once I save node with images and images data(alt,title)I can see them in the view node. But after few hours I noticed those images missing with image data. When I check file_usage table I can see entries. But in file_managed table there are no particular entries.

This doesn't happen all the time. In some nodes it disappear all the images and in some nodes(same content type) it disappear few images only.

Images uploaded via image field.

How I can resolve this? Please help.

Comment: Do you have any customisations to your site that might affect files or are you running only unmodified drupal core and contrib modules from drupal.org?

Comment: I don't have any custom codes that affect files. Yes, I'm using unmodified drupal core(7.17) and contrib modules from drupal.org. In my installation media module enabled. But for this particular content type I'm using image field. will that be a conflict?

Comment: first thing you want to do is update your version to 7.34 - there are some serious security holes prior to this version. It won't solve the problem but you want to make sure you update core immediately